# Does -u reduce the speed of ripgrep?

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I have read the man pages and documents online without getting a clear answer. It is stated that using -u with ripgrep will "Reduce the level of smart searching" as well as not searching the .gitignore file. I want the same level of speed searching but also don't want ripgrep to look at my gitignore. After testing for a while it's still inconclusive if it is the same speed or faster. I think ripgrep caches things making the reproducibility harder. Anyone have a definitive answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want ripgrep to respect your gitignore, then use `-u`. It's as simple as that. There is no definitive answer to your question. `-u` might make riogrep go faster because now it doesn't need to parse and match your gitignore rules against every file path. But `-u` night also make ripgrep slower if it needs to search more files that would have otherwise been skipped by gitignore. This is a fundamental trade off that depends on your specific circumstances.

The only way to know is to measure your own workload.